# Java regex to extract version

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java regex to strip off Java version from string I get from `java -version` command.

If the string is `java version 1.7.0_17` I need to extract 1.7 and 17 separately. Suppose if the string is `java version 1.06_18` I need to extract 1.06 and 18. Where first string should be only till the first decimal point. I tried with the below regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\"(.+)_(.+)\"");
```

But it extracts only 1.7.0 and 17, but I not sure how to stop still one decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

For the test cases you give, you could use this : `(\d+\.\d+).*_(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Re-read your question, my old answer didn't cover stopping at the first decimal point. 
This should solve your problem:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+[.]\\d+).*?_(\\d+)");
```

Tested:

```
 String input = "java version 1.7.0_17";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+[.]\\d+).*?_(\\d+)");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
 if (matcher.find()) {
     String version = matcher.group(1); // 1.7
     String update  = matcher.group(2); // 17
}
```

---

**Old version:**

Instead of finding the numbers, I'd get rid of the rest:

```
String string  = "java version 1.7.0_17";
String[] parts = string.split("[\\p{Alpha}\\s_]+", -1);
String version = parts[1]; // 1.7.0
String update  = parts[2]; // 17
```